# Dynamic, unique values for DOM elements

Tags: reactjs

I want advice on if my solution is conventional and/or if there are better, more common approaches using React for this situation:

I have a comments section. I retrieve a list of comments from the server as a prop to my functional component. Within the JSX, I map through each comment and, for each, return a TextArea to display the comment. One of the functionalities is that if you created the comment an edit button will appear, rendering the textarea editable.

This means that I need a unique identifier for each textarea, because once the user edits the comment's content and clicks the save button, I need to post to my server with the correct _id of the comment in the DB, along with the updated content.
My most idiomatic solution thus far is to use refs, code below:

1. I create a ref containing an array, a function to pass objects mapping the comment._id to the element, and add that to the commentRefs array whenever the function is called. The function to add to the ref array is the ref proeprty's value for the textarea:

   ```
    const addCommentRef = _id => el => {
    if(el && !commentRefs.current.includes(el) && el) {     
        const commentRef = {
            _id, 
            el, 
            content: '', 
        }
        commentRefs.current.push(commentRef);
    }
   ```

   }

   `<textarea ref={addCommentRef(comment._id)}`
2. On the textarea onChange, I call a function called editCommentRef, which maps through the commentRefs, compares the ID's passed as param with each _id value in the array and if found, updates the content to what has been typed into the textarea:

   ```
      const editCommentViaRef = _id => event => { 
   for(let i = 0; i < commentRefs.current.length; i++) {
    const commentRef = commentRefs.current[i];
    if(_id == commentRef._id) {
        commentRefs.current[i] = {
            ...commentRefs.current[i],
            content: event.target.value 
            } 
        }
    }
   ```

   }

   <textarea onChange= {editCommentRefs(comment._id)}...
3. Lastly, once the save button is clicked, its onClick handler calls a 3rd function named "saveCommentEdit", where it passes the _id of the comment. We again traverse through the commentRefs array and find the _id param matching the _id of the saved object. Once found, I have what I need to post to the server/db and update the comment:

   const saveCommentEdit = _id => {
   commentRefs.current.forEach((comment) => {
   if(_id == comment._id) {
   console.log('found comment to save to db ', comment._id + ' saving content - \n' + comment.content);
   }
   });
   }

<button onSubmit={saveCommentEdit(comment._id)} ...

This works, but is this too complicated, and are there any better and common solutions? Other solutions I have tried/considered:

- States - I imagine I would have the same issue with states as the state names need to be referred to in code, so I'd need a different variable name for each state. Also, states would require the entire component to re-render with every character typed into the textarea which seems more costly than refs.
- Document selectors - The simplest solution is to call a function which targets the DOM for the elements using "findElementById" and etc.. in which case I provide a unique identifier by making the ID of each textarea contain the comment._id. The obvious issue here is that targeting the DOM directly in a React app is discouraged, and fundamentally contradicting to the React framework.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `Ref` - it's meant for something else (to communicate with the `DOM`) and your task is different. You can store the edit state and `record id` from the database in each component. You can store the `author's id` to know exactly who can edit. On the server, update the record, provided that the id and author are the same. Also, you do not need to do any loops, a comment component can take care of sending data itself according to `OOP`.

For example you may have a table `comments` in your DB:

| id | post_id | author_id | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | user100 | cool |
| 2 | 1001 | user42 | hello |

Then get all comments by `post_id` if current user_id equal `author_id` you can pass to component property `editable` for show button `edit/save` (caption depends of mode)

Comment: Thanks very much! This helped a lot and I've re-written my code with a solution based upon this. Each comment is now a sole functional component which is returned during each iteration of the array of comments retrieved from server/DB. Now, I have opted for a state to store the value of the textarea, but in fact BECAUSE each comment is its own component and separate from the parent component (for the entire blog post), this causes re-rendering of only the comment component itself, when the state changes. No data needs to be re-rendered for the other comments or the parent component.